# Why does my mouse get slower and slower?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, dpi

I bought an excellent 5600 DPI mouse a few years ago, and it was really fast.

Now (I don't know why) it seems to be going a bit slower.  I haven't changed any settings or changed my operating system.

Could my mouse DPI be decreasing with time?

How do I get it back to its original speed?

Comment: What make and model of mouse?

Comment: I'm not sure... the sticker on the bottom of the mouse is a bit worn...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never heard of a mouse losing DPI over time, however that certainly doesn't mean it's not possible.

- Are you sure the whole PC isn't slowing down? When was the last time you reinstalled?
- Have you tried your mouse in another PC?
- Have you compared against a brand new mouse? You might just be getting used to the speed?
- Change your operating system settings, see if that helps.

Comment: My computer is not slowing down, that's for sure.  I think I have  gotten used to the speed, but I used a mouse benchmark to make sure that I was right when I said that my mouse is actually slowing down..

Comment: Which mouse benchmark program was it? Did you use it when you first got the mouse so you can compare results?

Comment: Yes.  I solved the problem, (its not worth posting how I did it).  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a hardware DPI switch on the mouse?  Mice with such high DPI ratings are generally gaming mice, so this may be the problem.  Check if the mouse drivers and utilities, if supplied with the mouse, are configured correctly as well.

Comment: Why would there be a problem if the mouse was a gaming mouse?... All drivers are up to date.

Comment: @wizlog, I'm referring to a hardware DPI switch on the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem recently - sometimes my mouse would work kinda ok, and other times it would just get really sluggish.

I just discovered what the problem was for me, and it was quite surprising; it had nothing to do with any software, but rather my mouse pad. I tried moving the mouse on another surface, and it moved fine - it was only on when I moved it on my mouse pad that I had the problem.

Temporary solution: I took a book from my bookshelf that had the perfect surface it seems on it's totally black covers - using the book as my temporary mouse pad, my mouse now behaves normally.

I'll have to get another mouse pad, one that's totally black, apparently.

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question